# How to check box automatically with table-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with table-react, I want to check some checkbox if my user have permission, for example my user has an id = 3 and he can see all of 3 companie with id: 5, id: 6, id: 7,

so I wanto to make a table with checkbox and the name of the all companies for my user admin and he can check or un check the permissions to see any companie.

I have and array fullfied with my companies:

```
const [empresas, setEmpresas] = useState([]);
```

this is the value of empresas:

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "uuid": "c0021f3e-7470-46fe-88d0-2ce1fa5d9296",
        "nombre": "Sección 15",
        "createdAt": "2023-07-18T22:50:52.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-07-18T22:50:52.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "uuid": "6e1bb7f4-0ebf-4033-8e94-62c0da6dc4fa",
        "nombre": "MetroCarrier",
        "createdAt": "2023-07-19T19:02:00.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-07-26T22:40:01.000Z"
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "uuid": "af451cd8-35d4-4974-b491-986984d64987",
        "nombre": "Tigon",
        "createdAt": "2023-07-26T22:29:11.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-07-26T22:29:11.000Z"
    }
]
```

and I have antoher array that have my user and the companies that he can see:

```
const [empresasActuales, setEmpresasActuales] = useState([]);
```

this is the value of empresasActuales:

```
[
        {
            "id": 2,
            "uuid": "QWERTY",
            "empresaId": 3,
            "usuarioId": 2,
            "createdAt": "2023-07-19T18:15:13.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-07-19T18:15:13.000Z",
            "empresa": {
                "id": 3,
                "uuid": "c0021f3e-7470-46fe-88d0-2ce1fa5d9296",
                "nombre": "Sección 15",
                "createdAt": "2023-07-18T22:50:52.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-07-18T22:50:52.000Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "uuid": "QWERTYU",
            "empresaId": 5,
            "usuarioId": 2,
            "createdAt": "2023-07-19T18:15:13.000Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-07-19T18:15:13.000Z",
            "empresa": {
                "id": 5,
                "uuid": "6e1bb7f4-0ebf-4033-8e94-62c0da6dc4fa",
                "nombre": "MetroCarrier",
                "createdAt": "2023-07-19T19:02:00.000Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-07-26T22:40:01.000Z"
            }
        }
    ]
```

so my user can see all of companies wiht id: 3 and 5 but not id: 11

but the checkbox is not checked automatically.

I tried to use react-table but didn't work. This is my code to get all my companies and the user info, this is working:

```
import { useTable, useRowSelect } from 'react-table';

useEffect(() => {
        const getUserbyId = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/users/${id}`);
                setPoliza(response.data.poliza);
                setNombre(response.data.nombre);
                setApellidoPaterno(response.data.apellido_paterno);
                setApellidoMaterno(response.data.apellido_materno);
                setEmail(response.data.email);
                setEmpresasActuales(response.data.usuarios_empresas);
                //setPassword(response.data.password);
                //setConfiPassword(response.data.password);
                setRol(response.data.role);   
                // Utilizamos el método map para obtener un array de empresaId                                
            } catch (error) {
                if(error.response){
                    setMsg(error.response.data.msg);
                }
            }
        }
        getEmpresas();
        getUserbyId();
    }, [id]);

const getEmpresas = async () => {
        try {
        const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/empresas');
        setEmpresas(response.data); 
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message)
        }    
    }
```

and this is the code for my table using react-table:

```
const columns = useMemo(
        () => [
            {
                Header: 'Seleccionar todas las empresas',
                accessor: 'nombre',
            },
            /*
            {
                Header: 'Seleccionar todas las empresas',
                accessor: 'nombre',
            }
            */
        ],
        []
    );
    
    const data = useMemo(() => empresas, [empresas]);
    const empresaIds = empresasActuales.map((empresa) => empresa.empresaId);    

    const {
        getTableProps,
        getTableBodyProps,
        headerGroups,
        rows,
        prepareRow,
        state: { selectedRowIds },
      } = useTable(
        {
            columns,
            data,
            initialState: {
                selectedRowIds: empresaIds.reduce((acc, empresaId) => {
                const row = data.find((empresa) => empresa.id === empresaId);
                if (row) {
                    acc[row.id] = true;                
                }
                return acc;
                }, {}),
            },  
            // Especifica el nombre del identificador en la propiedad idKey
            idKey: 'empresaId',
        },
        useRowSelect,
        (hooks) => {
          hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
                {
                    id: 'selection',
                    Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
                        <input type="checkbox" {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
                    ),
                    Cell: ({ row }) => <input type="checkbox" {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />,
                },
                ...columns,
            ]);
        }
    );

    useEffect(() => {
        // Cuando cambie el estado de la selección, actualizamos las empresas seleccionadas
        const selectedEmpresasIds = Object.keys(selectedRowIds).map(Number);        
        setEmpresasActuales(selectedEmpresasIds);
    }, [selectedRowIds]);
```

in this fragment of code, I made some validations to check if I find the id of the companie is in my user and this is workin, in this case shows two coincidences:

```
const row = data.find((empresa) => empresa.id === empresaId);
                if (row) {
                    acc[row.id] = true;                
                }
```

but when I tried to show in my table the companies checked automatically didn't work:

```
<table {...getTableProps()}>
                                                    <thead>
                                                    {headerGroups.map((headerGroup) => (
                                                        <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                                                        {headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                                                            <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}>{column.render('Header')}</th>
                                                        ))}
                                                        </tr>
                                                    ))}
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                                                    {rows.map((row) => {
                                                        prepareRow(row);
                                                        return (
                                                        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                                                            {row.cells.map((cell) => (                                                                
                                                            <td {...cell.getCellProps()}>{cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                                                            ))}
                                                        </tr>
                                                        );
                                                    })}
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
```

and this is how my table looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that the checkboxes are checked for the companies that the user can see.

In your code, you have correctly attempted to set the initial state of selectedRowIds for react-table, but there are some adjustments needed to ensure it works as expected.

Instead of using empresaIds.reduce to set the initial selectedRowIds state, you can create an object that holds the initial checked state for each company based on the user's permissions. Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
// Create a function to get the initial checked state for each company
const getInitialCheckedState = (companies, userCompanies) => {
  const initialCheckedState = {};

  companies.forEach((company) => {
    const userCompany = userCompanies.find((userComp) => userComp.empresaId === company.id);
    if (userCompany) {
      initialCheckedState[company.id] = true;
    } else {
      initialCheckedState[company.id] = false;
    }
  });

  return initialCheckedState;
};

const {
  getTableProps,
  getTableBodyProps,
  headerGroups,
  rows,
  prepareRow,
  state: { selectedRowIds },
} = useTable(
  {
    columns,
    data,
    initialState: {
      selectedRowIds: getInitialCheckedState(empresas, empresasActuales),
    },
    // Especifica el nombre del identificador en la propiedad idKey
    idKey: 'id',
  },
  useRowSelect,
  (hooks) => {
    hooks.visibleColumns.push((columns) => [
      {
        id: 'selection',
        Header: ({ getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps }) => (
          <input type="checkbox" {...getToggleAllRowsSelectedProps()} />
        ),
        Cell: ({ row }) => <input type="checkbox" {...row.getToggleRowSelectedProps()} />,
      },
      ...columns,
    ]);
  }
);

useEffect(() => {
  // Cuando cambie el estado de la selección, actualizamos las empresas seleccionadas
  const selectedEmpresasIds = Object.keys(selectedRowIds).map(Number);
  setEmpresasActuales(selectedEmpresasIds);
}, [selectedRowIds]);
```